# Error while trying to style React Select Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

Below is the code where I am using styled components to style the react select component

```
import { ForwardedRef, forwardRef } from "react";
import Select, { SelectInstance } from "react-select";
import styled from "styled-components";

export type SelectedItemType = {
value: string;
label: string;
};

export type SelectProps = {
options: SelectedItemType[];
ref: ForwardedRef<SelectInstance>;
onChange: (selectedItem: SelectedItemType) => void;
};

const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
border-radius: 10px;
`;

const SelectBox: React.FC<SelectProps> = forwardRef<
SelectInstance,
SelectProps
>(({ options, onChange }, ref) => {
return (
<StyledSelect
options={options}
ref={ref}
onChange={(newValue: unknown) => onChange(newValue as SelectedItemType)}
/>
);
});
export default SelectBox;
```

An error is being thrown at ref attribute which is attached as screenshot[image]

Can anyone suggest on how to resolve this error?